# Python / Pandas - put a list of dicts into a Pandas DataFrame - Dict Keys schould be the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

i have a list with a lot of dicts. Every Dict has 5 Key/Value Pairs.

**example Dict**

```
{ 
  'name': 'Demetrius',
  'number': '0001',
  'style': 'D',
  'text': 'Demetrius an der russischen Grenze. Er ist von Kiew...',
  'year': '1797'
}
```

**my Goal:**

my Goal is a DataFrame with the following order. Every Dict on its own row

```
>>> df
number  name        year  style  text
0001    Demetrius   1805  D      Demetrius an der russischen Grenze. Er ist von Kiew...
0002
```

**Code:**

d = the content of a textfile - list of dicts,

book = a dict like the example dict

```
>>>import pandas as pd

>>>df = pd.DataFrame()
>>>for book in d:
>>>    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(list(book.items()))])

>>>print(df)

    0                  1
0   name               Demetrius
1   number             0001
2   style              D
3   text               Demetrius an der russischen Grenze. Er ist von Kiew...
4   year               1805
0   name               Der versöhnte Menschenfeind
1   number             0002
2   style              D
3   text               Der versöhnte Menschenfeind - Fragment  Gegend...
4   year               1790
...
```

**Question:**

How can i achieve the style of the Dataframe (my Goal) directly or how could i change this existing df that i have my dict.keys an the columns and the values from the "number" key as the index?

**solution: - with thanks to jpp**

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d).set_index('number')
>>> df

         name                       style   text                                                year
number              
0001     Demetrius                      D   Demetrius an der russischen Grenze Er ist vo...     1805
0002     Der versöhnte Menschenfeind    D   Der versöhnte Menschenfeind - Fragment Gegend...    1790
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pd.DataFrame` constructor accepts a list of dictionaries directly. This will be more efficient than appending repeatedly to an existing dataframe. Here's a demo:

```
d1 = {'name': 'Demetrius', 'number': '0001',
      'style': 'D', 'text': 'Demetrius an der...',
      'year': '1797'}

d2 = {'name': 'ABC', 'number': '0002',
      'style': 'E', 'text': 'Some text',
      'year': '1850'}

L = [d1, d2]

df = pd.DataFrame(L)

print(df)

        name number style                 text  year
0  Demetrius   0001     D  Demetrius an der...  1797
1        ABC   0002     E            Some text  1850
```

Comment: thank you!! hours of complicated thinking and trying....
but it is so easy. Why i didn found that easy solution in the docs? Nevermind, i accept your answer as fast as stackoverflow let me to do it.